# Jquery jscrollpane plugin error

Tags: jquery, safari, google-chrome, jscrollpane

I get this error when I try and implement jSrollpane in Safari 4:

**TypeError: Result of expression '$drag[0]' [undefined] is not an object.**

Then i get this error when i try the same thing in Chrome:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined**

But why? it works fine in FF.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see this problem on any of the example jScrollPane pages ( http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#examples ) in Safari or Chrome. Can you provide a URL showing the problem? What versions of jScrollPane and jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that jQuery does not manage to resolve the child selector (“parent > child”), thus both 
"$track" and "$drag" are set to undefined values:

```
$track = $('>.jScrollPaneTrack', $container);
$drag = $('>.jScrollPaneTrack .jScrollPaneDrag', $container);
```

As a result, the scrollbar does not initialize, and simply does nothing
Replacing the previous lines with a "dumbed down" version fixes the issue:

```
$track = $container.children(".jScrollPaneTrack");
$drag = $track.children(".jScrollPaneDrag");
```

Comment: The reason for the child selector is so that you can implement nested jScrollPane instances and they work correctly (e.g. http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html ) - in all of my tests the child selector works correctly so there must be another problem here...