# Style scrollbar with jScroll

Tags: jquery, html

I ve been trying to style some scrollbars with jScroll on a theme I installed for a friend, but it's returning

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined
```

I tried another jQuery plugin called tinyScrollbar and it's doing the same. I m  !  sure what the problem =. I can change it with CSS but it won't work in Firefox which = really annoying. Any ideas why it won't work?

Url: http://spicyjentertainment.com/welcome.html

This = the div that = suppose to scroll

```
<div class="wrapper" id="scrl">
```

And the CSS

```
#scrl {
    height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;

}
#scrl:hover {
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

EDIT

```
var initDrag = function()
            {
                ceaseAnimation();
                currentOffset = $drag.offset(false);
                currentOffset.top -= dragPosition;
                maxY = trackHeight - $drag[0].offsetHeight;
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined
                mouseWheelMultiplier = 2 * settings.wheelSpeed *     maxY / contentHeight;
            };
```

Comment: You're loading two versions of jQuery, 1.7.2 and 1.8.3 - you need to eliminate one of them. I am getting TypeError: $drag[0] is undefined as the error.

Comment: I just saw that. Just one version is loaded now and it s still not working.

Comment: $drag[0] is undefined. Can you post the code relevant to that?

Comment: see my edit please. I just copy pasted it from the console. I found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131629/jquery-jscrollpane-plugin-error but no luck.

Comment: Where are you defining $drag?

Comment: I have no idea, it's just a plugin I found online http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html, people seem to use it and it works for them.

Comment: You need to look and see where they are defining $drag, that is where your snag is. $drag is the undefined part, the script is trying to read the offsetHeight of it.

Comment: thanks ... I found it but I have no idea how to fix it `var $drag = $('>.jScrollPaneTrack .jScrollPaneDrag', $container);`

Comment: Are any of the objects in the selector defined?

Comment: and that s where you lost me :)

Comment: I just noticed that you load the jScrollPane.css after the JavaScript. You may want to move that up to where the other CSS is loading.

Comment: thank you ... same thing. I ll keep looking for some other plugin. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

tinyscrollbar needs a div structure to be present.. You only have 1 wrapper div. read the instructions.

```
    <div id="yourscrollbar">
    <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="overview">

tekst..



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```